# How to allow entry in NumericUpDown only via up and down arrow

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

I have a `NumericUpDown`  where up and down arrows are there to enter integer. All that is set up but I want to disable entering the value manually by clicking. I want the user to be able to change value only via up and down arrow. can someone guide me how to achieve that.

[image]

Currently I have added **ValueChanged Event** to handle some of the logic. But that event does not get triggered when the value is manualy changed. Please guide me.

[image]

Comment: What does "UI Control" mean?  A UserControl? Custom Control? That looks like and sounds like a NumericUpDown, is that what it is?

Comment: Numeric Up Down Control

Comment: It does get fired when the user leaves the control - until then any value is just tentative. No matter how they enter a value, it will be forced to be between Min and Max, so why do you need to disable typing?   Also, the resulting `Value` will be a Decimal

Comment: This is contrary to the design of the control.  If you don't want the behavior of a NumericUpDown, then why use one?  Just use a textbox, disable entry, and handle the key presses to increment and decrement.

Comment: @DonBoitnott The OP wants the mouse to do the work only.

Comment: @LarsTech Am I reading it wrong, then?  I guess I came to the same conclusion as David...arrow keys on the keyboard.  Not arrow buttons.

Comment: NumericUpDown1.Controls(1).Enabled = False

Comment: This is an assumption, but I feel like what is being asked is that the OP doesn't want the user to be able to click inside the textbox of the control and type a number, but instead wants to only allow the user to click the up/down arrow buttons that are part of the control. Which if that is the case, David Wilson's answer is what I would expect to work.

Answer (score 3):

This will fire every time someone presses a key when the control has focus.

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

All it does is effectively intercept the keypress, and tell the system that the keypress has been deal twith in your sub, and no further processing of the keypress will happen.

Comment: Correct.  And wrong.  Note the crux of the question was " I want the user to be able to change value only via up and down arrow."

Comment: @DonBoitnott  
I understood that to mean that the control to be limited so that it is only to be used via mouse clicks. The above code forces this.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to handling key events, you can make the edit part of the control readonly:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DirectCast(Me.NumericUpDown1.Controls(1), TextBox).ReadOnly= True
    DirectCast(Me.NumericUpDown1.Controls(1), TextBox).BackColor= Color.White
End Sub
```

NumericUpDown is a composite control consisting a custom `TextBox` and a custom control for `Buttons` part. You can do anything with those controls. Handling those events, changing properties and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no topic about this for c#.
if you came here because you tried to do this in c# like me, then try this:

((TextBox)NumericUpDown1.Controls[1]).ReadOnly = true;